# center circular progress react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a circular progress that runs in the center of the display, without changing other design elements being displayed, i tried using grid and other material design components but it still shows at the top left of the display

```js
 <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: 'background.default',
          minHeight: '100%',
          py: 3
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth={false}>
          <ProductListToolbar />

          <Box sx={{ pt: 3 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
              {projects.length == 0 ? (
                <Box
                  position="relative"
                  alignItems="center"
                  display="inline-flex"
                >
                 <CircularProgress />

                 
                </Box>
              ) : projects.length > 0 ? (
                renderList
              ) : (
                'no data availablle'
              )}
            </Grid>
          </Box>

          <Box
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              pt: 3
            }}
          >
            {/* <Pagination color="primary" count={3} size="small" /> */}
          </Box>
        </Container>
      </Box>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```